# Function called inside a loop doesn't show any screen output

Tags: python

I'm unable to figure out how `return` works. In the following code, the first two pieces of code work just fine, but it fails to return any output at all when using return in a loop(#3).

```
# 1
def test(x):
    return 'Testing'*x

test(3)
#2
def tst():
    return 'Testing'

tst()

#3
for i in range(2):
    tst()
```

Comment: `return` returns control from the current function or method. Also `return value` just returns that value and never prints it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third one works, what's happening is that you don't do anything with the output because it's in a `for` loop.

We can see the results if we would print out the value returned from `tst()` function, i.e:

```
def tst():
    return 'Testing'


for i in range(2):
    print(tst())
```

And the output of the program will be:

```
Testing
Testing
```

The first 2 function calls in your code work because python just prints the value of the last line you called, but because it's in a `for` loop, it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The python REPL is not equivalent to the actual python interpreter. In the REPL/IDLE, the last expression evaluated implicitly prints. When you have a for loop, the REPL does not implicitly print the last expression, which is why you *think* that nothing's happening. You can see that's not the case if you explicitly print everything:

```py
print(test(3)) # prints "TestingTestingTesting"
print(tst()) # prints "Testing"
for i in range(2):
    print(tst) # prints "Testing" twice
```

Comment: A great example, but since the op is new to python, I'd try to not confuse him with terms like REPL, interpreter and IDLE. But that's just my own opinion.